# .NET Core Web API 5.0 build errors

Tags: .net-5

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   NETSDK1005  Assets file 'D:\Working On\Gra\Gra\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp5.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.  Gra C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100-preview.1.20155.7\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets  234

I've just create ASP.NET Core Web Application, and then when I run, I it's show message errors!

Comment: You can use .net core 3.1. Any specific use case to use .net 5 perview? or is it just for learning purpose?

Comment: For any specific use case and Long term project.

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath it's not a Preview, it's a fully supported RC with a Go Live license. There are no build problems

Comment: He is using preview as mentioned in the error `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100-preview.1.20155.7\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sd`

Comment: `netcoreapp5.0` there's no such target. It's `net5.0`. Did you edit the csproj manually perhaps? Or use an outdated SDK? Install the *latest* .NET 5 SDK and just create a new project, eg `dotnet new web` or `dotnet new webapp`

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath in that case, it should be upgraded, not go back to 3.1

Comment: .Net 5 has no production release yet. These are RC. And I do not recommend preview or RC for serious development, I would prefer LTS/RC over preview for serious project, hence I recommended 3.1 and also I checked the reason.

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath this question isn't asking about opinions on whether to use a Go-Live version,  it's asking about a specific problem.

Comment: `Besides, there are entire application categories that simply can't be done with .NET Core 3.1.` - that's why I asked if there is any specific usecase (check my comment please). Also, don't see that as an opinion (if that was an opinion I would not have asked further questions), that's a suggestion which opens door for discussion and eventually reaches to conclusion. Like we are discussing and several points are coming out like .net 5 is in RC etc. I feel we should definitely put our opinion and suggestion and that's one of the purpose of `comment` section. I didn't put it in `answer` section.

Answer (score 15):

In my publish profile the Target Framework was set to NET5.0.
Changed it to NET6.0 and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 12):

Update to Nuget 5.8
Clear the local cache

```
error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'project.assets.json' ....
```

Try updating NuGet.exe to the 5.8.0 version or above:

```
nuget update -self
```

if you prefer to update the nuget version in Visual Studio, just follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/nuget-update) steps. Then, clear NuGet cache:

```
dotnet nuget locals all --clear
```

[Download Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/downloads)

found [here](https://ivanderevianko.com/2020/11/fixed-error-netsdk1005-assets-file-doesnt-have-a-target-for-net48)

Comment: Updating Nuget to latest (5.8) resolved compilation in VS 2019 (I do not use VS 2019 Preview) for a simple .Net 5.0 console app. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed it for me on an Azure Devops pipeline that had a 'Use Nuget' pipeline stage.

Answer (score 8):

Delete the 'obj' folder and re-build the project.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an extremely old .NET 5 preview. [ASP.NET Core Preview 1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-5-preview-1/#whats-new) specifically had *no* new features, it was essentially a version number change. There's no `netcoreapp5.0` framework target any more, it's `net5.0`.

The latest version is [5.0 RC1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0) which is [feature-complete and supported in production](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0-rc-1/). Install it and create a new project with, eg `dotnet new webapp` or `dotnet new webapi` etc.

This version is supported by the latest [Visual Studio 2019 Preview](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/) version.

Comment: Thanks @Panagiotis Kanavos