# Problem after transferring files to another system (error NETSDK1)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

After I import the files from another system to my system, I get the following error

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NETSDK1005  Assets file 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\project1\project1\project1\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net5.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net5.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.    project1    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    267

Comment: Have you `Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net5.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project`?

Comment: How should I be sure?

Comment: Run it by hand.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore   Maybe need to use the `--force` option

Comment: I recovered but the following error occurred  Failed to restore C:\Users\user\Desktop\project1\project1\project1\project1.csproj (in 165 ms).

Comment: Delete the 'obj' folder and re-build the project.

Answer (score 0):

Update to Nuget 5.8 Clear the local cache

```
error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'project.assets.json' ....
```

Try updating NuGet.exe to the 5.8.0 version or above:

```
nuget update -self
```

if you prefer to update the nuget version in Visual Studio, just follow this steps. Then, clear NuGet cache:

```
dotnet nuget locals all --clear
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979408/net-core-web-api-5-0-build-errors)